# Parse 1.3 compatibility issue with WP8

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, push-notification, parse-platform, push

I wanna understand if Parse.com SDK is fully compatible with WP8 and WP8.1?
I checked out some examples and seems version 1.3 has some problems both with wp8 and wp8.1...
Here in stackoverflow a user says in wp8 we need to use version 1.2.16 to make sure it works well and he's right... In fact the version 1.3 doesn't work instead of 1.2.16 that works well...

I would like to use Parse for Android\WP8\WP8.1 project but i'm undecided...
Someone already used parse in WP8\WP8.1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the folks at parse.com have a fix since september 24th, but they have not released anything up until today:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/327073484113608/